# code-map refresh without rearranging the layout?

Tags: visual-studio-2013, code-map

I recently upgraded to VS ultimate 2013, as it was free for my msdn License.

I'm playing around with the codemap function, and I for the most part think its very good. But what I dont like is when I add a new function to the map, it kinda blows up to one of the default views.

Is it possible to disable this?

All I really want to acheive is to get the calls chronologically. From top to bottom.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure what you mean by "blowing up the default views" but here are some hints:

- Have a look at the Layout menu. Perhaps disable "Incremental Layout" or re-layout by choosing one of the options (top to bottom etc.)
- How do you add new functions to the map? Do you drag and drop from Solution Explorer? What do you expect to happen?
- Upgrade to VS 2015. We've made many improvements to CodeMap in VS 2015. You can use VS 2015 side by side with VS 2013.

Comment: Disable incremental layout helped somewhat, I can live with that, thanks. If the "Show methods this calls" would align the entries, and show them chronologically automatically it would be awesome. Will upgrade to vs2015 when my subscription will give it to me;)

Comment: Hi @TerjeSolem - I'm glad this helps! Could you clarify what "chronological order" means in context of methods - would you like them ordered by their creation time? I was under the impression all MSDN subscriptions give you the latest software. VS 2015 is pretty cool, but I am somewhat biased  in saying that :)

Comment: By chronological, i guess i really mean in which order they are called when using left to right layout. And I didn't realize that there is no longer a Premium and Ultimate, but rather a Enterprise that replaces those two.